# How to make Google understand that is not self serving reviews?

Tags: seo, schema.org, search-results, rich-snippets

I run a blog where I write reviews of restaurant and/or pubs, and also user can leave rating (aggregateRating)

For years, my reviewRating was indexed fine.

Some months ago, in serp reviewRating has been replaced in favor of aggregateRating, I think because of this google rule

> Ratings must be sourced directly from users. [*]

Now, also aggregateRating was removed, I suppose because of this?

> Pages using LocalBusiness or any other type of Organization structured data are ineligible for star review feature if the entity being reviewed controls the reviews about itself. For example, a review about entity A is placed on the website of entity A, either directly in their structured data or >through an embedded third-party widget. [*]

My blog has a lot of reviews of many different places.
How can I make google understand that these are not self serving reviews?

This is an example of my page markup:

```
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org/",
 "@type": "LocalBusiness",
 "name": "Resturant Name",
 "description": "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu eros sed eros gravida fermentum non sed...",
 "image": {
   "@type": "ImageObject",
   "url": "https://i.picsum.photos/id/310/700/525.jpg",
   "width": 700,
   "height": 525
 },
 "Review": {
   "@type": "Review",
   "name": "Resturant Name",
   "reviewBody": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu eros sed eros gravida fermentum non sed ante. Maecenas malesuada orci sapien, vitae hendrerit mauris eleifend in. Integer facilisis dignissim scelerisque. Nam quis dictum metus. .",    "author": {
     "@type": "Person",
     "name": "Jhon Doe"
   },
   "datePublished": "2013-11-08T14:41:19+01:00",
   "dateModified": "2020-06-02T21:24:19+02:00",
   "reviewRating": {
     "@type": "Rating",
     "ratingValue": "4.3",
     "bestRating": 5,
     "worstRating": 1
   }
 },
 "aggregateRating": {
   "@type": "AggregateRating",
   "ratingValue": 3.4,
   "ratingCount": 32,
   "bestRating": 5,
   "worstRating": 1
 },
 "address": "Street Address",
 "priceRange": "€€",
 "telephone": "12346789"
}
```

When tested with [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) I've no error and the [previews shows aggregateRating indeed](https://www.google.com/search?prvw=AHHjJUMZuYZMXJAcl-vzUkbGgEZxeJIlOA&q=previewid%3A05d26abe-8ac4-4d08-9dc5-eb832940a33a&useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Linux%3B%20Android%207.1.1%3B%20Nexus%206%20Build%2FN6F27M%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F66.0.3359.106%20Mobile%20Safari%2F537.36&filter=0&gws_rd=cr&newwindow=1&igu=1)

What if I also add "[publisher](https://schema.org/publisher)" property? Would be it helpful?

[*] from [google technical guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet#technical-guidelines)

Comment: Do you have more than one review of each place from different users that contribute to the aggregate rating?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, however you can see here an example https://snipboard.io/xvsefP.jpg

The first box contains the reviewRating, and the second one the "AggregateRating"

Users doesn't leave review, just their vote in the second box

Comment: I think your scenario may come under critic review: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/critic-review

Comment: Thank you Tony, I will try it in some pages